# Change NET Core version for UWP application

Tags: uwp, nuget, .net-core

For UWP application I need to use methods from ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor class. After adding nuget package System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, this class is available, but there is just only one available function. The reason for this is that project reference assembly from netstandard1.0 directory, than from netstandard1.5 directory where is fully implemented class. 
Is there any way to change project configuration that libraries from netstandard1.5 will be referenced ? or maybe drop whole reference to Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package and replace it with references to particular dlls ?

---

I ask how to reference particular dll, or replacing package with references to dlls. than how to target whole other framework.

Answer (score 3):

Universal Windows Platform (UWP) does not support .NET Standard Library 1.5 for now.

Form [.NET Platforms Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#net-platforms-support), we can see the highest version of .NET Standard that UWP supports now is .NET Standard Library 1.4.
[image]

So now in UWP, we can't use APIs that build on top of .NET Standard Library versions 1.5. However in the next version of UWP, it will support .NET Standard 2.0, then you should be able to use the fully implemented class.

> We’ll ship updated versions of .NET Core, Xamarin, and UWP that will add all the necessary APIs for supporting .NET Standard 2.0.

For more info, please see [Introducing .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/).

Comment: Thanks for answer. But still have few questions. What about replacing Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package with separate dlls ? I have tried this, but some libraries (mscrolib, VisualBasic) cannot be added. Where can I find description what classes/methods are implemented in particular net standard ?

Comment: @codefox With the UWP, the .NET Core is included as a set of NuGet packages in your app. When you create a new project, you’ll see only the general Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package dependency, but it contains the full set of official Microsoft .NET Core assemblies that are tested and relevant to UWP apps. So if we don't use this package, we will need to add a lot of other packages. And UWP has a different application model from .NET Core App, I'm afraid we can't  support .NET Standard 1.5 by just replacing the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package.

Comment: @codefox I also can't find description about what classes/methods are implemented in particular .NET Standard. But I think you can always find these info by using "Go to Definition"  in Visual Studio.